# numerical linear algebra span/null

Tags: linear-algebra

Intro to Numerical linear algebra proof questions. I am not sure how to begin any of the 2 problems given. Any help will be appreciated.

Given $A \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$, recall that 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{R}(A) := \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n: y = Ax,~x\in \mathbb{R}^n\} \tag{range of $A$}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(A) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Ax = 0 \} \tag{null-space of $A$}
\end{equation}
The rank-nullity theorem states that 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{rank}(A)+\text{nullity}(A) = n. \label{rnt}
\end{equation}

Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $\| u \|_2 = 1$. If $P=uu^\top$, prove that

(i)
 $\mathcal{R}(P) = \text{span}\{u\}$.

(ii)
 $\mathcal{N}(P) = \mathcal{H}(u) := \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \langle u,v \rangle = 0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\mathcal{R}(P)=\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n: y=u(u^Tx), x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$$

Note that $u^Tx$ is a scalar and it can be chosen to be non-zero.

$$\mathcal{N}(P)= \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n: u(u^Tx)=0 \}$$

Sicne $u$ is non-zero, what values must $u^Tx$ take?